# Ruby delete hash value from all hash elements except the last one

Tags: ruby

I've got a hash:

```
hash = [{:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>Sun, 20 Sep 2020, :vat=>0.0},
       {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>Tue, 20 Oct 2020, :vat=>0.0},
       {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>Fri, 20 Nov 2020, :vat=>0.0},
       {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>Sun, 20 Dec 2020, :vat=>0.0}]
```

I want to replace values for `transaction_date` by `nil` everywhere except the last one to have something like this:

```
hash = [{:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>nil, :vat=>0.0},
       {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>nil, :vat=>0.0},
       {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>nil, :vat=>0.0},
       {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>Sun, 20 Dec 2020, :vat=>0.0}]
```

Is there any nifty way to do so without iterating through the hash by `each` ?

Comment: Can you show it in actual Ruby code? This won't work in Ruby, it has syntax errors.

Comment: Do you mean the last one in array order, or in order by date?

Comment: It's also ironic that your `hash` is an `Array`.

Comment: Ok, it's array of hashes - my mistake. I mean the last element of that array - I expect result as I wrote in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to just scrub them all but one:

```rb
hash.reverse.drop(1).each do |e|
  e[:transaction_date] = nil
end
```

Since these are object references in the array you can manipulate them like this.

Comment: `hash[0..-2]` is more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating an intermediate array you can write:

```
arr.each_with_index { |h,i| i == arr.size-1 ? h : h[:transaction_date] = nil }
  #=> [{:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>nil, :vat=>0.0},
  #    {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>nil, :vat=>0.0},
  #    {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>nil, :vat=>0.0},
  #    {:net_amount=>100.0, :transaction_date=>"Sun, 20 Dec 2020", :vat=>0.0}
]
```

Here `arr` is the array from the example named `hash`. I couldn't bring myself to naming a variable "hash" when it holds an array. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Single line solution is

```
hash[0...hash.length-1].each{|a| a[:transaction_date] = nil}
```